# Mean Average Precision (mAP) metric curve for a Faster R-CNN object detection Pascal VOC custom dataset use pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, object-detection, torchvision, faster-rcnn

I want to calculate and curve a graph for mAP/epochs for a training dataset.
Here is my training code. I used this github source below to add in relevent code. But there were some errors because that was for YOLO. While I used faster r-cnn and code with pytorch for a pascal voc custom dataset.

Could you please help me how to add "IOU" and "mAP" calculation code to curve mAP/epochs graph??

[mAP and IoU metrics](https://github.com/aladdinpersson/Machine-Learning-Collection/tree/master/ML/Pytorch/object_detection/metrics)

my training code:

```py
num_epochs = 50
vector_row =[] 
for epoch in range(num_epochs):       
    loss = train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, train_loader)
    vector_row.append(loss) 
    print('epoch [{}]:  \t lr: {}  \t MSE: {}  '.format(epoch, lr_scheduler.get_last_lr(), loss))
    lr_scheduler.step()
```